# How to make ExpansionTile title clickable?

Tags: flutter, dart, expand

I mean, I want to go to another view when the title is tapped and expand/collapse when the icon in ExpansionTile is tapped.

here's my code:

```
ExpansionTile(
                  title: categories.isEmpty
                      ? Text('no items')
                      : Text(categories[i].name),
                  children: getSubCategories(i),
                );
```

Answer (score 1):

`ExpansionTile` expands by design, if you want the children to be tappable either choose a widget that has onTap or wrap it with `GestureDetector`.

```dart
ExpansionTile(title: Text('Expansion tile'), children: [
  ListTile(
    leading: const Text('List tile'),
    onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).push(
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return Container();
        },
      ),
    ),
  ),
  GestureDetector(
    child: const Text('Wrapped'),
    onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).push(
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return Container();
        },
      ),
    ),
  )
])
```

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution. Just wrap the text Widget into an Inkwell.